# How to convert string (containing location) to an array

Tags: javascript

I have a string which contains location:

```
var string = "[ 30.733315, 76.77941799999999,City,6,10/28/2013 10:28:39 AM]"
```

How to convert this to an array, so that i can get

```
arr[0] = 30.733315,
arr[1] = 76.77941799999999 so on.
```

`String.split()` is not working here.

Comment: Why do you have this string? Where did it come from? What's the format supposed to be? In particular, what if the name of the city has a comma in it?

Comment: its coming from the Google map API. City doesn't have a comma.

Comment: @robieee Then the documentation will probably have some sort of explanation of what to do with the data.

Comment: and why doesn't split work? It should, if you remove the brackets first and trim the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cross-browser solution:

```
var string = "[ 30.733315, 76.77941799999999,City,6,10/28/2013 10:28:39 AM]";

var arr = string.replace(/\[|\]/g,'')
                .replace(/ /g,'')
                .split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

Split on `[`, `]` and `,`.

`]` must be escaped in the split regex

```
var arr = string.split(/[[,\]]/).filter(function(el) { return el.trim(); })
```

`Array.prototype.filter` is required to remove empty strings from the array.

A more readable version of `filter` would be:

```
arr.filter(function(el) {
  return el.trim().length === 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "[ 30.733315, 76.77941799999999,City,6,10/28/2013 10:28:39 AM]";
string = string.replace('[',"['");
string = string.replace(']',"']");
string = string.replace(',',"','","gi");

console.log(string);
arr=eval(string);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var mystring= "[ 30.733315, 76.77941799999999,City,6,10/28/2013 10:28:39 AM]"
var list = mystring.split(',');
```

Output:

```
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
  alert(list[i]);
}
```

[String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) Splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.